# Android Best Practices for Images

Tags: java, android, performance

I dont have a specific question im just looking for general best practice information.

In my app i am using a custom view to draw specific items that move and what not. However i do have items that require the user to touch them.

How i have it now is that the custom view takes up the entire screen. And all the images are drawn as bitmaps using a canvas to draw them. Then i implement an onTouch method. The ontouch method essentially passes the x and y variable to my custom handler.

My custom handler literally checks the upper and lower bounds of all of the bitmaps that i have drawn to determine if the user touched the bitmap.

so literally its like

```
touchX = 10
touchY = 10

if(touchX > bitmap.x && touchX < bitmap.x + bitmap.size && touchY > bitmap.y && touchY >     bitmap.y + bitmap>size)
{
     image was touched
}
```

the logic may not be correct but thats not the question.

Is this the way to do it? Or should i be implementing specific android layouts and embedding my custom view for drawing inside a different layout and then use imageviews inside like a relative layout and set an ontouch listener.

Thanks for the insight.

Comment: May sound simple, but if you are making your own view, can't you extend View and just simply use the onTouch listener of some sort? That would seem like a simple and elegant way to do it.

Comment: Thats what i currently am using. I have one onTouch listener for my view, and in that onTouch method i check specifically whether or not each image that i have draw has been touch by checking the bounds of the image.

I was just wondering if that is the way to do it, or should i be using imageview and setting specific listeners for each image

Comment: with that, i dont think you can use an imageview in a custom view. You have to use an android specific layout such as relative layout or grid layout. I think, i could be wrong

Comment: Short "answer": read the developer training site for Android: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html. In particular this part should apply to your question: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/display-bitmap.html

Comment: If you have only 4-5 images, the processing should be simple, but if it becomes like 10-20, it could be stressing for the phone. A suggested solution would be to make your own grid, like a map, 1A, 2A, 3A, 1B, 2B, 3B... put them in a dictionary and give them a boundary, 1A -> 0 < x < 50; 0 < y < 50. 2A -> 50 < x < 100; 0 < y < 50; And so on. On click of the screen, get the points, and round them up to nearest multiple of 50. Then, just access the dictionary based on the keys (N(1)). That should speed it up, I think

Comment: And whatever images fall into that grid area, do your method check on that.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. So you believe the implementation of having one onTouch method will work, instead of having separate listeners for each image?

Comment: and the reason i ask, if because using imageview will have to be outside of the custom view i have, which i think would be a pain to implement a custom view along side a relative layout for the imageviews. I dont know how it will look.

Comment: Android has a `Rect` class, which have convenient `contains(int x, int y)` and `intresect(Rect r)` methods.

Comment: ^ That would be a better approach.

Comment: ah, that is a good idea. So again having onTouch method seems to be ok when detecting if a bitmap has been pressed over using an imageView. Do you agree?